# Highcharts x axis shows numbers after max limit

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highchart (column), categories on x axis are evaluated dynamically. I have two options max and min in x-axis configuration. But when x axis categories are greater than max , it shows numbers like 13,14...etc on x-axis. I want that x-axis should show labels only for categories supplied and not pad numbers to reach up to max limit.

here is fiddle showing the problem [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/z1yencny/)

Comment: What you have given is an line chart, fix your fiddle pls

Comment: If you don't specify the xAxis min and max, you will get the result you expect. Please check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0g06482a/

Comment: You can set the max value dynamically, by checking the length of the data array.

Comment: [Just pad the categories](http://jsfiddle.net/z1yencny/1/) array with blanks `categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec','','','','','']`

Answer (score 1):

The axis `max` property does not work the way you are thinking. It is not a cap value that will stop the values from going higher, it is the constant max value of the axis.

If you provide a max value, and you don't provide enough categories to reach the max, the chart fills in with the only thing it knows to do.

As mentioned in comments, you have a few options.

The most common and useful is to simply not specify a max; let your categories and data determine the max automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to simply play around with formatter: http://jsfiddle.net/z1yencny/4/

```
        labels: {
            formatter: function(){
                var str = this.value;

                if(!isNaN(str)){ 
                     str = '';  
                }

                return str;
            }
        }
```

Of course, above solution won't work with numbers in categories. However, simply change condition to compare value with value under the category index.

Comment: you saved the day

Answer (score 0):

If you supply chart with enough labels then they will be used instead of numbers.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/z1yencny/2/

```
categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug']
```